# Any tool for tracking transaction/events on local blockchain? (Querying data from private blockchain network?)

Tags: transactions, events, tools, dapptools

I am looking for an adequate tool to help me track events and/or transactions on my local/private blockchain network.

For example: If transferring NFT's (on locally running ganache or hyperlegerBesu). I want to be able to track its transfer history (the addresses it had been transferred from && to.)

All the tools I found are only valid for big public blockchains like ETH, Avalanche, etc. And that is not my use case.

Bonus points if it has some nice GUI to showcase this to non-technical people.

NOTE: My project is looking to move from Hyperleger Besu to Avalanche, is if some tool might work with Avalanche test networks, that might be ok too, (not ideal, but its something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading [BlockSkout](https://github.com/blockscout/blockscout) repo on github, this tools provides:

> comprehensive, easy-to-use interface for users to view, confirm, and
> inspect transactions on EVM (Ethereum Virtual Machine) blockchains

its looks like etherscan but you can configure it based on your local blockchain.

Comment: Short Question: The BlockSkout will allow me to query data and trace (for example) the history of ownerships for specific NFT. Is something like that possible with this tool?

Comment: I don't think it is working the same as your example. but it works as Ethereum etherscan.if you want to query data and use API I recommend using graph (https://thegraph.com/en/) but it just works in testnets and main net(not local)

Comment: Yeah, I guess I would need something Like a graph, but for local blockchain.

Comment: I guess this link helping you:
https://thegraph.academy/developers/local-development/

Comment: Yeah, I think this is what I need.